# How to get ResultSet element in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, resultset

- How can I get the last element of *ResultSet* in **Zend Framework 2**?

I can get the last element if I convert the object into array but I want to keep my object and get the last element.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky task because ResultSet is simply an iterator (and it cannot be rewinded), so I think that the only solution would be to alter the query to sort in different order, but if you could describe use case more clearly, maybe we could work out better approach.